# Java how to create a layout using GridBagLayout?

Tags: java, swing, layout, jframe, layout-manager

I am trying to create a layout where there is a header that contains a logo and/or text string, followed by a 3x3 grid. I was looking through the Java API on their website but couldn't find anything on how to create a 3x3 grid with a header. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just write the sample code about your issue
3x3 buttons gridlayout a label at start of gridlayout

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class GridBag extends JFrame
{
private JPanel pan;
public GridBag()
{

    GridLayout g=new GridLayout(3,3);
    pan=new JPanel(g);
    pan.add(new JButton("1"));
    pan.add(new JButton("2"));
    pan.add(new JButton("3"));
    pan.add(new JButton("4"));
    pan.add(new JButton("5"));
    pan.add(new JButton("6"));
    pan.add(new JButton("7"));
    pan.add(new JButton("8"));
    pan.add(new JButton("9"));
    JLabel l=new JLabel("grid layout");
    l.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);


    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(l,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(pan,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    setSize(1000,500);
    setVisible(true);




}
public static void main(String args[])
{
    new GridBag();
}

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a [BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) and a [GridLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html), then read a [tutorial about Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/layoutlist.html) on the java website.

Comment: Yep, you'll also need to nest the GridLayout-using container into the BorderLayout using one in the BorderLayout.CENTER position, and place the header in the BorderLayout.PAGE_START (also known as BorderLayout.NORTH) position. 1+